# generator of the cyclic group : $(\mathbb{F}_p^*, \times)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would like to prove that there exist an element $m$ in the cyclic group : 
$$(\mathbb{F}_p^*, \times)$$ with $p \geq 3$ prime such that $m$ and $4m$ are generator of this group.

Yet I don't know at all how to proceed, any hint or ideas are welcome :)

Comment: How do you define $4m$? Do you want $m^4$ maybe, given that your group uses multiplication as a rule? Or do you really want $4m$? Btw: In both cases, such an element does not always exist.

Comment: I want $4m$, I think it does exists because $p$ is a prime number $ \geq 3$

Comment: I don't see the link with my problem...

Comment: @Bemte do you have a counter example ?

Comment: @mercio My counter example was $p = 2$. As this is now excluded, I asked my computer and it told me that the claim is true for all primes $p$ with $3 \leq p \leq 1000$...

Comment: @1231 But you haven't really explained why you think it is true, since you don't know a proof. Is this an exercise somewhere?

Comment: @DerekHolt This is an exercice my teacher gave me, so this is of course true for very prime $p \geq 3$

Comment: If $\omega$ is a primitive root mod $p$, then $4 = \omega^{2j}$ for some $j$, so it would be sufficient to prove that, for any $j$, there exists $k$ such that $k$ and $k+2j$ are both coprime to $p-1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt your claim would follow from Bunyakovsky's conjecture: Consider $f(k)=k^2+2jk+(p-1)j^2$, $f$ has negative discriminant so is irreducible and no prime could divide $f(1),f(-1)$ and $f(0)$ at the same time, thus $f(k)$ take  infinitely many primes $q$, take $q$ such that $q \nmid p-1 $ then $k(k+2j)$ and $p-1$ would be coprime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I exaggerated with Bunyakovsky's conjecture :-), the claim it's actually  an easy application of the chinesse reminder theorem.

In the notation of @DerekHolt comment, write $p-1=2^{n_0}p_{1}^ {n_1}\cdots p_{r}^{n_r}$ where $p_i$ is an odd prime for $i=1,2,\ldots,r$. Since each $\mathbb{Z}/p_i \mathbb{Z}$ has at least that $3$ elements exists $a_i$ such that $a_i \not\equiv0,-2j \,\,(\text{mod} \, p_i)$. Now take $k$ such that $k\equiv1 \,\,(\text{mod} \, 2)$ and $k\equiv a_i \,\,(\text{mod} \, p_i)$, then $k$ and $k+2j$ are coprime to $p-1$  (because $k\equiv a_i \not\equiv0,-2j \,\,(\text{mod} \, p_i)$ and both $k$ and $k+2j$ are odd ).

Comment: Yes I thought an argument like that would work!